# Which is true for an orthogonal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have the following exercise and I don't know if my attempt is correct. Let $v_1,...,v_n$ an orthogonal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have:

1. $||x||^2=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\langle x,v_i\rangle$
2. $||x||^2=\frac{1}{P}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\langle x,v_i\rangle^2$ if for all $i$ we have $||v_i||^2=P$.
3. $||x||^2=\frac{1}{P}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\langle x,v_i\rangle$ if for all $i$ we have $||v_i||=P$.
4. $||x||^2=\frac{1}{P}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\langle x,v_i\rangle^2$ if for all $i$ we have $||v_i||=P$.
5. $||x||^2=\frac{1}{P}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\langle x,v_i\rangle$ if for all $i$ we have $||v_i||^2=P$.

**My attempt:** Since $v_1,...,v_n$ is a basis, there exists $a_1,...,a_n$ not all equal to $0$ such that $$x=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i$$ We have that $$||x||^2=\langle x,x\rangle=\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i\right)\cdot\left(\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n a_jv_j\right)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_ia_j(v_i\cdot v_j)$$ and since $v_1,...,v_n$ is orthogonal, we obtain $$||x||^2=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i||v_i||)^2$$Also $$\langle x,v_i\rangle=a_i||v_i||^2$$For all inmediatly we have that $1$ is, in general, false. 
If $||v_i||^2=P$ for all $i$, we have that $||x||^2=P\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2$, and for this, 2 and 5 are false in general. If $||v_i||=P$ for all $i$, we have that $||x||^2=P^2\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2$, and for this, 3 and 4 are false in general. 
Is my attempt correct? Thanks for help me!!!

Comment: One of these options is actually correct. I think you're confusing yourself with the $a_i$s. While none of your calculations are incorrect, try expressing your sums in terms of inner products $\langle x, v_i\rangle$ and $P$, instead of in terms of $a_i$ and $P$. Hopefully you'll then see which of these options is true.

Comment: Ok, so continuing your calculations, $\lVert x\rVert^2=\sum_1^n (a_i\lVert v_i\rVert)^2$ and $\langle x,v_i\rangle=a_i\lVert v_i\rVert^2$, so you have $\langle x,v_i\rangle^2=(a_i\lVert v_i\rVert^2)^2=(a_i\lVert v_i\rVert)^2\lVert v_i\rVert^2$, so that $\lVert x\rVert^2=\sum_1^n\langle x,v_i\rangle^2/\lVert v_i\rVert^2$; do you see which option is correct now?

Comment: Consider that $a_i$ represent the coordinates of x. Since the basis is only orthogonal but is not normal- the basis vectors have magnitude different than 1, then you should focus on options that contain $<x,v_i>^2$